# Equivalence relation proof on R¹²

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations

There's a set D in R¹²

{x1, x2, x3, ... , x12 | (x1)²+(x2)²+(x3)²+...+(x12)²⩽1}

A relation is defined on R¹² such that a and b both belong to D or a and b both do not belong to D at the same time.

Prove that this is an equivalence relation.

How i proved it which i feel is incorrect is by showing that if a and b both belong to D then using the same language i proved reflexivity symmetry and transitivity. For example i proved transitivity by saying if a ∈ D and b ∈ D, and b ∈ D and c ∈ D then a ∈ D and c ∈ D

Is there any other way of proving this? Is this correct?

Comment: "A relation is defined on D such that a and b both belong to D or a and b both do not belong to D at the same time."  This sentence doesn't make much sense.  If the relationship  is "on D" then a and b can only belong to D and never don't.  Did you mean the is a relationship of $\mathbb R^{12}$?  If so $D$ itself is irrelevent  and this is pretty trivial.  If $a R b$ and $b R c$ then either $a\in D,b\in D$ and as $b\in D$, $c\in D$.  Or $a\not \in D, b\not \in D$ and as $b \not \in D$ $c\not in D$.  The equivalence classes are simply $D$ and $D^c$.  This is about as easy an equ rel as there is

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What $D$ is actually irrelevant.  It happens that $D$ is a unit sphere, but it doesn't matter $D$ could be any set at all.

Now you claimed that the relation was defined on $D$.  I assume you are mistaken.  If not then this relationship is that $a$ is related to $b$ no matter what $a$ and $b$ are the only elements we are considering are points in $D$.  .... so this would be a relationship where $a$ relates to $a$ and $a$ relates to $b$ means $b$ relates to $a$ and $a$ relates to $b$ and $b$ relates to $c$ means $a$ relates to $c$ because *EVERYTHING* relates to *EVERYTHING*.

I think you mean the is a relation on $\mathbb R^{12}$ where $a R b$ means either $a,b\in D$ or $a,b \not \in D$.

This is pretty trivial.  The universe is devided into two equivalence classes:  $D$ and $D^c$ where every element in $D$ is related to every element in $D$ and to no elements in $D^c$ and every element of $D^c$ is related to every element of $D^c$ and to no element of $D$.

To prove this is an equivalence relationship:

Reflexive:

For any $x \in R^{12}$ either $x \in D$ or $x \not \in D$.  If $x \in D$ then $x \in D$ and $x R x$, and if $x \not \in D$ then $x \not \in D$ and $x\not \in D$ so $x R x$.

Symmetric:

If $a R b $ then either 1) $a \in D$ and $b \in D$ or 2) $a \not \in D$ and $b \not \in D$. If 1) then $b\in D$ and $a \in D$ so $b R a$.  And if 2) then $b\not \in D$ and $a \not \in D$ so $b R a$.

Transitive:

If $a R b$ and $b R c$ then either 1) $a\in D$ and $b \in D$ and as $b R c$, $c\in D$.  Or 2) $a \not \in D $ and $b \not \in D$ and as $b R c$ then $c \not \in D$.  In 1) we have $a\in D$ and $c\in D$ so $a R c$ and in 2) we have $a\not \in D$ and $c\not \in D$ so $a R c$.